# how to capture telephone number dialled event when a user clicks/touches a telephone number linked with tel: uri scheme

Tags: javascript, html, touch

I want to log all the events where a user touched and dialled a number displayed on my webpage displayed on android/iOS devices? Is it possible?

Comment: How is the number displayed on your page?

Comment: You can detect "clicks (touches)" the url, but that's as much as you can do. There is no way for JS to determine whether the user actually called the number.

Comment: @JanHančič I am using `<a href=tel:1234` scheme.

Answer (score 0):

*There are at least three methods to solve this problem:*

**1. Check the href on click()**

You can listen to the `click()` event on the links and detect if their `href` starts with `tel:`:

```
$( 'a' ).click( function () {
    var href = $( this ).attr( 'href' );
    var tel = /^tel:/i.test( href );
    if ( tel ) {
        alert( 'A telephone link was clicked: ' + href );
        //if you don't want the default action (dial ) to happen, return false, otherwise don't return anything
    }
});
```

JSFiddle Live: http://jsfiddle.net/c7CRG/2/

**2. Using a class flag**

Also if you have control over the HTML and can put a class name in all the `<a>` links that contain a phone number, there's no need to do the parsing in the above algorithm:

```
$( 'a.telephone' ).click( function () {
    alert( 'A telephone link was clicked: ' + $( this ).attr( 'href' ) );
    //if you don't want the default action (dial ) to happen, return false, otherwise don't return anything
});
```

**3. Using advanced JQuery syntax**

You don't have to use regexp to parse the href attribute. JQuery has [an interesting syntax](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) for that:

```
$( 'a[href^="tel:"]' ).click( function () {
    alert( 'A telephone link was clicked: ' + $( this ).attr('href' ) );
});
```

And here is a JSFiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/c7CRG/7/

Comment: This will not tell the OP if the user actually _dialled_ the number, which is part of the question, but impossible to do.

Comment: yeah it is impossible. I don't understand the downvote though. I'm just trying to help and the answer is not wrong. it just doesn't satisfy the part that is impossible.

Comment: You say _"It's easy"_, you don't mention it's impossible. The answer is very misleading, since you're implying your code does what the OP asks for.

Comment: @AlexStack, capturing the event part is ok, its possible to capture every touch on a page. But the tricky part is, did the user actually dial the number or just touched and did nothing...

Comment: @Kumar: you can use the fact that dialing a number shows the phone interface and (probably) closes the browser. In that case listen for window.onunload and check if it is happenning right before a <a> link is clicked. You can save the timestamp on every click and then on window.onunload check if the timestamp is quite recent. But I'm not sure if window.onunload is the method to check. maybe some other event will be triggered right before the view is changed from browser to phone.